# The quotient group of a ring and the intersection of an ideal is isomorphic to a subring of the product of the quotient ring and each ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Is it true that:

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $I, J$ be ideals of $R$. Then for some subring of $S \subseteq R/I \times R/J$ we have
> $$
> R/(I \cap J) \cong S.
> $$

This would be equivalent to the Chinese Remainder Theorem for non-coprime ideals. I've tried constructing a function $\phi: R/(I \cap J) \to R/I \times R/J$ and showing its injective.

Comment: Why not use the map from the CRT, show the kernel is $I\cap J$, and conclude that the *image* is isomorphic to the quotient, using the isomorphism theorem? The “meat” of the CRT is not the map, it’s the fact that it is surjective when $I+J=R$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the map from CRT? You mean the natural isomorphism $\phi: R \to R/I \times R/J$, and if so what would this map resemble?

Comment: What do you, “resemble”? You send $r$ to $(r+I,r+J)$. That’s the map that the CRT tells you is an surjective when $I+J=R$.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I didn't realise CRT applied to rings as well, thanks for the help I finished the proof. I will add it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proof

We construct the natural homomorphism
$
\varphi: R \to R/I \times R/J
$
such that
$$
\varphi(x) = (x+I,x+J).
$$
We know that
$$
\ker \varphi = \{x\in R: x\in I, x\in J\} = I \cap J.
$$
Since the $\text{im } \varphi$ is a subset $S$ of $R/I \times R/J$ so by the first isomorphism theorem
$$
R/(I\cap J) \cong S.
$$